# URL is not opening in edge in robot framework however browser is launched

Tags: robotframework, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to run my Robot Framework script in edge but its giving

> WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error

while trying to launch the app.
Used Below snippet:

```
Open Browser   https://www.amazon.com    edge

Maximize Browser Window
```

I could see browser launched that too in maximized state but URL was not displayed like this

[image]

Also, my Teardown keyword is also not running(i.e. browser instance is not getting closed) which should ideally run if test case fails or gets completed.

Teardown step

```
Close Browser
```

In SeleniumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot(default keyword to run on failure)  it is showing that
"Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open."

Also my same script is running successfully in Chrome Browser.

I am not sure if its bdriver compatibility issue, bcoz below Selenium-Java script is running fine

```
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Does the version of the webdriver match the browser version?

Comment: Yes. They are in sync. Browser version is: 84.0.522.59 and have downloaded the driver version for release 84